# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string. (Image error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to create a component in react native.

The example of the component is:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'


const MyComponent = ({Text, Image}) => {

  return (
    <Text>{Text}</Text>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/HeaderLogo.png')} />
  )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  Text: PropTypes.string, 
  Image: PropTypes.string,
}

export default MyComponent
```

If i remove the  component, everything works nice and well, but when i try with the image component, it returns the error on the following image:

[image]

(It works with a icon, but not with a image.)

the component is imported as follow:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
```

If i change the import to:

```js
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent'
```

i get another error (As following):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **Text** and **Image** as arguments (props) to your function.

1. Not sure where you are using the image prop; if you aren't you should remove it.
2. **As for the Text argument, you need to change this to *text* with lowercase *t***. Anything you pass as prop is essentially an argument to a function. Using an Uppercase T conflicts with the JSX Text element, which is used in your render function and is typed **< Text >** in order to render the relevant UI element.

in short, remove all capitalised references to the **text** and **image** arguments you pass in. Your code should look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'


const MyComponent = ({text}) => {

  return (
    <Text>{text}</Text>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/HeaderLogo.png')} />
  )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string, 
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `Text` and `Image` as props, because you import them. Uppercased names are used for components.

Also React expects one top level element to render, and you're passing two. To make this work you'll need to wrap them in `View`:

```
const MyComponent = ({text}) => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
      <Image source={{uri: require('../../assets/images/HeaderLogo.png')}} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing and using Image like this

```
import myIMage from '../../sourcefile.png'

const Component = (props) => {
return (
<View>
<View />
<Image source={myImage} style={{height: 100, width: 100}} /> //style is important here 
</View>

export default Component;
```